# Отключить ui-mobile от jquery-mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

Друзья, такая тема, подключил я `jquery-mobile`, для осуществления `swipe` на смартфонах, но мне этот `js` весь стиль изгадил.
Он автоматом меняет мой стиль на свой, кнопок, текста и т.д.

Искал в инете решения, но они частично помогли, но не все убирает.
К тегу `<html>` автоматом приписывается класс: `class="ui-mobile"`, да и стиль текста поменялся.

Пробовал такие методы:

До инициализации `jquery-mobile` писал скрипт:

```
<script src="инициализация простого jquery"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
});
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
```

Ставил не alpha-версию, все равно также, дело не в версии.

Ставил также такие теги, тегу `<body data-enhance="false" data-role="none">`
Также не помогает, стиль кнопок мой становится, а вот простые ссылки меняются под свой `jquery-mobile` стиль, да и в `<html>` ставится класс `ui-mobile`.

Может кто-то сталкивался с этим.

UPD: Что заметил, проблема только с теми текстами, которые выводятся через `php` через `echo`. У меня просто языковые файлы и отображаю текст в выбранном языке `echo $lng['site_name']`. Т.е. тот текст, который выводится через php, автоматически присваивается стиль от Jquery-mobile

Comment: Т.к. я использую только `swipe` подключил отдельно плагин `TouchSwipe` и использовал `swipe` полёт нормальный, и все стили остались как есть.